# Is there any way to achieve the dynamically update the option list in material-ui or anyother way than select2?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, material-ui

I need this functionality of Dynamic option creation. For instance if I have to create an option as abc(if that option doesn't exists) it should add in this search.

https://select2.org/tagging

[Adding abc in search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o76f.png)
[abc has been added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6jCy.png)

Comment: It's need to read from a Backend code. For example make a table in your DB for search bar and if client add new thing into, they automatically called an API to added in DB. (you can even use Local Database but it's not show for other client )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.